I've got a long list of data for items purchased by customers, but I want to group the data into categories. How do I do it?

It is a very long list of mixed items and I want to categorise them. How can I do it on excel other than manually categorising them which is near impossible
Tried conditional statements but i dont think it's possible to work

What about countif() or countifs(), or create lists of items for specific categories.

Have a look at what you can do with countif() and unique():

As you posted an image, I went minimalist on the example data, if you had given copiable example data but the functions shown work.
